# Ngourd C# BDD Cucumber

Tags: c#, cucumber, bdd

http://code.google.com/p/ngourd/downloads/list

above is the link for NGourd, a C# BDD testing framework. Question is How do i download this? I don't see any link for downloading. I see that under the "Wiki" tab there is a "QuickStart" link and no other link to download. thanks for you help. Please supply with a link in your answer so i can download this and run throug the testing of my program. thx again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you'd have to download the source; see http://code.google.com/p/ngourd/source/checkout

It will help if you have a SVN client; if you are on Windows then my preference is [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/), but any would do.